# Listening to changes made to flex Date Object

Tags: actionscript-3, data-binding, date, flex4

I have a date object and I want to listen to any changes made to it. The changes can be made by either directly assigning another date object

```
var newDate:Date = new Date(2009,10,9);
date = newDate;
```

and by using

```
date.setTime(timeInMilliSeconds)
```

I tried using BindingUtils.bindsetter:

```
var myWatcher:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateDate,date,"time");

private function updateDate(value:Number):void
{
    trace(value);
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I wish to know what am I doing wrong or if there is someother way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a variable bindable before you can watch it (or you need to dispatch the change events for it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `PropertyChange` / `PropertyChangeEvent` mechanism.

```
objectProxy = new ObjectProxy(newDate);
objectProxy.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, propertyChangeHandler);

private function propertyChangeHandler(evt:PropertyChangeEvent):void {
    // Do what you want
}
```

The code above is an excerpt from an example found at [blog.flexexamples.com](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/27/detecting-changes-to-an-object-using-the-flex-objectproxy-class/).

Comment: This works for objects but when i try to implement this for Date object, the changes are not reflected.
Thanks!